# How to get the Image URL of rct-image-store to upload image through api

Tags: react-native

How to get the image url from the rct-image-store? I cropped image using ImageEditingManager and it returned me rct-image-store://0. Now I need to upload this image to the server. How do i get the URL to the image so i can upload it?

Here is the code I used

```
  ImageEditingManager.cropImage(
        photoURI,
        transformData,
        (croppedImageURI) => {
          console.log('crop success', croppedImageURI);
        },
        (cropError) => console.log('cropMyError', cropError)
      );
    },
    (error) => undefined,
  );
```

croppedImageURI gets logged as

> rct-image-store://0

How do i get the url to this image so I can upload it to the api server?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -5):

```js
var testDemo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
            return {
                imageURISource: {
                    uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'
                }
            }
        },

        render: function() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image
                    style={{height:250,width:300, borderColor: '#f099f0',borderRadius:3}}
                    source= {this.state.imageURISource}
                    />

                ImageEditingManager.cropImage(
                        photoURI,
                        transformData,
                        (croppedImageURI) => {
                                console.log('crop success', croppedImageURI);
              
                                //get croppedImageURI and set, it will update Image
                                this.setState({imageURISource: {uri:croppedImageURI}})
                                
                        },
                        (cropError) => console.log('cropMyError', cropError)
                );
                    
            </View>
            );
        },

});
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are having and the outcome you expected?

Comment: Please check the question again. This shows how to crop the image, it doesn't handle how to upload it to the server.